# C#: Hidden base method used when object passed as argument. Any workaround?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm new to inheritance. I've noticed that if you take an object that has been constructed from a partial class, and pass it as an argument to a function that accepts its base type, the base methods are used even if they have been hidden in the partial class.

It would be useful to be able to use inherited objects interchangeably. Is there a workaround or alternative in the language that would allow me to pass objects as arguments in this way?

I've written some example code to demonstrate what I'm talking about:

```
public class Enemy
{
    string[] baseLikes = new string[] { "loitering", "puppies" };

    public string[] GetLikes()
    {
        return baseLikes;
    }
}

public partial class Skater : Enemy
{
    string[] uniqueLikes = new string[] { "skateboarding" };

    public new string[] GetLikes()
    {
        string[] likes = base.GetLikes();
        return likes.Concat(uniqueLikes).ToArray();
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void WriteEnemyLikes(Enemy enemy)
    {
        string[] likes = enemy.GetLikes();
        Console.WriteLine("This enemy's likes: ");
        foreach (string like in likes)
            Console.WriteLine("- " + like);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Skater skater = new Skater();
        WriteEnemyLikes(skater);

        Console.ReadLine();

        // Output:
        // This enemy's likes:
        // - loitering
        // - puppies

        // Notably absent: skateboarding
    }
}
```

Comment: user override and virtual for your methods to get proper inheritance.

Comment: You don't want a *partial* class, just use `public class Skater : Enemy` for inheritance. A partial class is just a single class that's defined in (potentially) more than one file.

Comment: you want the base method to be `virtual`, and avoid `new` on the derived method.  Use `override`.

Comment: Thank you so much to everyone for your helpful feedback. In retrospect, it's obvious to me that learning inheritance from generated windows forms code was a big mistake...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are doing inheritance *all* wrong.

First off; you should almost **never** use method hiding. It just doesn't have a lot of practical purposes. To allow derived objects to *override* base class functionality (a concept called polymorphism), you use the `override` keyword, and `virtual` on the base class:

```
public class Enemy
{
    string[] baseLikes = new string[] { "loitering", "puppies" };

    public virtual string[] GetLikes()
    {
        return baseLikes;
    }
}

public class Skater : Enemy
{
    string[] uniqueLikes = new string[] { "skateboarding" };

    public override string[] GetLikes()
    {
        string[] likes = base.GetLikes();
        return likes.Concat(uniqueLikes).ToArray();
    }
}
```

If you still want to use the base class method in the derived class, invoke it with `base()`. There is also no reason for the derived class to be `partial` unless you are looking to define another part of it in another file. The real reason for `partial` classes is generated code, and that isn't happening here.

Answer (score 6):

There are some severe issues with your code:

1. `partial` does not do what you think

   `partial` is meant to split up a class declaration over multiple places (or
   files). It has nothing to do with inheritance.
2. You should use `virtual` methods.

   Declare the method in the base class as `virtual` and use `override` in a 
   derived class. The methods will exhibit just the behavior you want, i.e. that a call to a method will depend on the type of the instance and not the static type of the variable:

   ```
   public class Enemy
   {
       string[] baseLikes = new string[] { "loitering", "puppies" };

       public virtual string[] GetLikes()
       {
          return baseLikes;
       }
   }

   public class Skater : Enemy
   {
       string[] uniqueLikes = new string[] { "skateboarding" };

       public override string[] GetLikes()
       {
           string[] likes = base.GetLikes();
           return likes.Concat(uniqueLikes).ToArray();
       }
   }
   ```
3. `new` is meant to indicate *hiding* a method from the base class in a derived class. The method will only be called if you use a variable of the derived class (it is invoked statically).

Answer (score 0):

The other answers hit the nail on the head: inheritance does not work the way you think it does.  They are all great answers, I just want to expand on their answers a bit and make a suggestion to help simplify your code.

Instead of using a string[] and the `GetLikes()` method, have you considered using a `List<string>` property?

For example:

```
public class Enemy
{
    public List<string> Likes { get; set; }

    public Enemy()
    {
        Likes = new List<string>()
        { 
            "loitering", 
            "puppies" 
        };
    }
}

public partial class Skater : Enemy
{
    public Skater()
    {
        Likes.Add("skateboarding");
    }
}
```

With this approach you can have one property that all the "likes" reside in, without the need for the method.  Plus you do not need to override any virtual method.

I created a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1UTCvs) that shows it in action.

Comment: you could even just make the property virtual and let each one override it